# Casting `sum` result to an integer in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a query in Ecto the includes the sum of a column containing integers. I'm using MySQL as the database.

e.g.

```
result = Repo.one(
  from v in Vote,
    where: [post_id: 1],
    select: sum(v.direction)
)

IO.inspect(result)

# Yields: #Decimal<5>
```

The result is returned from Ecto as a `#Decimal<x>`. When I encode this to json it's cast to a string. Ideally I'd like it as an integer, especially as the result will always be an integer from the database.

What's the best way to cast this?

Here's my schema:

```
schema "votes" do
  field :direction, :integer

  belongs_to :user, Linklet.User
  belongs_to :link, Linklet.Link

  timestamps()
end
```

I have managed to achieve the intended result by using MySQL's `CONVERT` function within a fragment, but it doesn't seem like the most robust approach:

```
result = Repo.one(
  from v in Vote,
    where: [post_id: 1],
    select: fragment("CONVERT(?, SIGNED)", sum(v.direction))
)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want it to be integer why would not you store in the database as integer in the first place? Also, please show your schema file for `Vote`.

Comment: `Decimal.to_integer(result)`?

Comment: @mudasobwa the `direction` column is an integer. I'm not sure why the result is a decimal. Schema posted

Comment: @Dogbert ideally I'd like the type-casting to occur at query time to avoid having to map over the result.

Comment: Are you sure that that column is an integer in the database?

Comment: yes, it's also declared as an integer in the migration. I've checked the database itself and it is an integer. Maybe it's a mysql thing...

Answer (score 4):

You can cast to an integer at the database level using [Ecto.Query.type/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#type/2):

```
result = Repo.one(
  from v in Vote,
  where: [post_id: 1],
  select: type(sum(v.direction), :integer)
)
```

Comment: you should mention that this maybe was not a feature of old ecto library

Answer (score 3):

`SUM` in MySQL returns a `DECIMAL` value for integer inputs.

> The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value for exact-value arguments (integer or DECIMAL), and a DOUBLE value for approximate-value arguments (FLOAT or DOUBLE).

<sup>[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)</sup>

So you have two options: either convert the value to `SIGNED` like you're already doing, or convert the Decimal value to an integer using `Decimal.to_integer/1` in Elixir.